# Can I save Burmano from Himself?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Darling Burmano is the in-house chef for Lookout Landing, and very early in my adventure, he asked for an apple. After completing this quest, the next time I returned to Lookout Landing, the Chef was nowhere to be found, and another NPC with a less-memorable name was complaining that dear sweet Burmano had gone to the Hyrule Castle dining hall in order to learn a new recipe!

But that place is crawling with monsters! Obviously, I set out at once, cleaving my way through the horrors of Hyrule Castle (those black horriblins! *shudders*), to wind up... at the Dining Hall, with a hapless Burmano, standing above a cooking pot, muttering about Crispy Fried Rice.

Is there anything I can do to save Burmano from himself? A derelict castle is no place for such an endearing chef! I successfully cooked a Crispy Fried Rice in front of him, but he didn't seem to notice...

Comment: +1 because I did the exact same thing and was surprised this did not respond to my actions.

Comment: Is there a quest associated with this situation?

Comment: You have to beat Ganondorf, this will cause the blood moons to stop so you can clear out hyrule castle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having now completely beaten the game (including the late-game event that takes place at Hyrule Castle), Burmano remains where he is in the Hyrule Castle Kitchen. (But safe, at least!)

Just like poor Wabbin in Gerudo Town, it doesn't look like there's any follow-up here.